# Apache 2.4 Combine Require ip and Require not ip for specific location

Tags: apache

Im trying to configure my apache to restrict access to a certain url, except for all ips in a specific range, with some exceptions.

My idea was the following:

```
<Location "/uebung3">
Require ip 123.1.0.0/16
Require not ip 123.1.1.0/24
Require not ip 123.1.3.0/24
Require not ip 123.1.5.128/25
Require not ip 123.1.7.0/24
Require not ip 123.1.11.0/24
Require not ip 123.1.12.0/24
</Location>
```

However, this does not work for some reason, as the require not does not seem to be in effect.

When I restart my apache i get the error

```
negative Require directive has no effect in <RequireAny> directive
```

Am I missing sth in regards to order? Or is there simply no way to use require not to exclude sth from a previous filter?